# How to install zend framework on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, zend-framework2

I have install zend framework using skeleton application on my machine ie ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I follow following steps.

1. create application base folder and run the following commands.
2. cd/myproject/dir
3. git clone git://github.com/zendframework/zendSkeletonApplication.git
4. cd ZendskeletonApplication
5. php composer.phar self-update
6. php composer.phar install
7. using the apache web server set virtual host

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName zf2-tut.localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zf2-tut/ZendSkeletonApplication/public
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
        <Directory /var/www/html/zf2-tut/ZendSkeletonApplication/public>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
   ```
8. after i edit hosts page from etc folder and add there 
   **127.0.0.1       zf2-tut.localhost localhost** this line.
9. at last run application as http://zf2-tut/localhost
   but it shows uable to connect server.

Tell me Where it go wrong.
Help

Answer (score 2):

It' not ZF-related problem.

You have added `zf2-tut.localhost` to the hosts file, but you are trying to access it with `http://zf2-tut/localhost` instead of  `http://zf2-tut.localhost`.

Can you make sure that the domain is consistent - including webserver's vhost.